# Reputation changes laggy when looking at my own profile

Tags: support, status-bydesign, profile-page

For some reason, the reputation I earned for my last answer (`20` points so far) was not showing up when visiting my own profile (although it had the blue `20` icon next to the tab), but it **did** show when I browse my profile without being logged in.

Proof:

[image: lag]

Although I refreshed the left window several times, I guess this could be explained by caching or something like that. But it is the first time that this happened to me, so I thought I'd report it anyway...

On a related note: I really hate how [possible-bug](/questions/tagged/possible-bug) becomes [support](/questions/tagged/support).

Comment: caching would be my guess ... stuff is cached heavily in that area

Comment: It's not that possible-bug becomes support. Logically, it's that "support" is the starting tag - if _later_ someone finds out that there is a bug, then there is a bug. But starting with possible bug is not that meaningful, because it implies a speculation about the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Things are cached here, separately for yourself and anonymous users (since *you* can see your downvotes, etc.) so unless some anonymous user had hit your profile in the last 10 minutes, you did a live load of the reputation tab in that anonymous window, which is why it was "fresher."

We have changes in the pipe that'll likely result in a *lower* cache time for reputation-related things, but not *no* cache, there'll always be some amount of lag there, it's [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), so the DB server doesn't explode.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed information on how these things are cached.